# DATE format in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

Just a small issue with some coding within Oracle SQL Developer.
This is my first time away from SQL Server and i'm already confused as to what I have got wrong.

I'm just trying to insert some data into a table but i'm reaching an error that states;
`Error report - ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

I have the date field in my table set up as data type DATE.
All I am trying to insert is some basic information;
`INSERT INTO BasicUsers  VALUES(2125, 'Dave', 'Forest', 'John', '1998-10-25', 30.54);`

I have done some research on the internet and there is nothing solid for me to understand.
I have tried altering the date format to YYYY-MON-DD so 1998-Oct-25 but that isn't working either.

Can anyone explain what I have done wrong here and how I can rectify this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: `'1998-10-25'` is a string, not a date. SQL Server does not support date literals, but Oracle does : `DATE '1998-10-25'`.

Answer (score 5):

`'1998-10-25'` is not a `DATE` data type; it is a string literal.

Instead, use a `DATE` literal:

```sql
INSERT INTO BasicUsers  VALUES(2125, 'Dave', 'Forest', 'John', DATE '1998-10-25', 30.54);
```

Or use the `TO_DATE` function with a format model to explicitly convert from a string to a `DATE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO BasicUsers
  VALUES(2125, 'Dave', 'Forest', 'John', TO_DATE( '1998-10-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), 30.54);
```

Don't rely on implicit conversions from a string to a `DATE` as Oracle will implicitly try to convert the date to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. Your query is effectively:

```sql
INSERT INTO BasicUsers
  VALUES(2125, 'Dave', 'Forest', 'John',
  TO_DATE(
    '1998-10-25',
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  30.54);
```

If the session parameter does not match then your query will raise an exception. Since the user can change their session parameters at **ANY** time then you can never rely on this format to be consistent between users or even user's sessions so you should always be explicit about the conversions that you are performing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DATE` prefix:

```
INSERT INTO BasicUsers 
    VALUES (2125, 'Dave', 'Forest', 'John', DATE '1998-10-25', 30.54)
```

I would also advise you to include explicit column names for the insert.  For instance, the values could be defined in a different order from how you are providing the values.

Comment: Thank you! I will do, just wanted to complete a bulk batch insert first to get data into the tables, just trying to familiarize myself with Oracle.